# Working with Excel 4.0 for work, trying to use a button to launch a python script

Tags: python, excel, python-2.5, excel-4.0

So, the shop where I work use Excel 4.0 for all its inventory management and orders.
Since the guy before me left without explaining anything, I inherited an old system that *works*, but is... eh.
The bosses ***don't*** want to change to a new Excel nor another program, so I must do what I can with what I have.

Now, I've made a script in python 2.5.4 (this version is needed because the newer versions won't work on the Windows 98 computer they use...) to automate some processes that would be impossible with Excel 4.0 macros, and the script works perfectly for what I need.
But since the bosses want to "only work with Excel", and won't want to go outside of Excel and click the script icon to start it (or, heaven forbid, open cmd and start it manually), I would need to put a button in Excel to start the script.
I've tried to sift through the macros available, but except perhaps "Initiate" (which I don't wholly understand as of now), I can't think of a macro to interact with the script, and haven't found much help with what's available online...

SO, could anyone please help me in making the macro for the button? The only thing the button would need to do is to start the python script, there's no other interactions needed, the rest is done by the script.

Like, the script "foo.py" is in the same folder as "bar.xls", and I only need a button in "bar.xls" to launch "foo.py".
Thanks.

Comment: You do not have to keep using Excel 4 macros and, in fact, you should not. The boss is not the one maintaining the code. If they are unable to understand why you shouldn't be using Excel 4 macros then they shouldn't be making decisions about it. Push back. You can't allow them to make bad decisions. You're the person they hired to work on this, they should listen to you.

Comment: NOTE: I have retrofitted quite a few legacy systems in my day. It's likely that they don't actually need to run Win98 like they think they do. I have maintained some old NT systems that had software people thought they need to run only on Windows NT and I can get it to run on Windows 10.

Comment: I would agree with you, but one of them wrote the macros in 1998, and they work with the macro sheet opened everyday.
And if they say they want to work with that, they want to work with that.

Comment: The year is now 2022. Those macros had a good life. It's time to put them down. Plus, VBA is easier to maintain. The old dog should know these tricks aren't even new.

Comment: Look mate, I agree with you.
But they are 60 years old, and won't change their ways, so I need to work with what I have. They WANT to work with microsoft 98 and excel 4.0, and the last guy tried to convince them to work with other stuff, but never convinced them, so I need to make it work while in excel 4.0.

Comment: My condolences. This guy sounds like the guy at the place I worked in college who couldn't fathom how the card reader would know what job it was running when we quit buying colored cards and went to all buff colored cards. He also didn't understand how he would do his job when we hauled the card punch/reader out of the raised floor (and shed tears at its passing). Of course, he'd been doing all his editing digitally for 2-3 years by then, but actually got to hold a card while he did it and thought that's where the magic was.

Comment: As a thought, if this guy isn't the boss, maybe talk to the boss, demonstrate that the process will run on hardware less ancient than the user. Maybe also point out some security vulnerabilities in Win98. Shouldn't be hard to find one or two. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan They're both the bosses and they're both not wanting to change their systems. They use it for the inventory of the store, and it works, and since they'll probably retire within the decade, they don't want to adapt too much.
The last guy and I made incremental changes over time, and they're fine with that, but an overhaul is out of the question.
Also, the system is not connected to the internet in any way, so I doubt it'll cause problems.

Anyways, I managed to find something and shared my answer, so if anyone has the same problem as me, it won't be another unanswered question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found a roundabout way, so I'm gonna share it with y'all.

```
MacroName
=LAUNCH("cmd",1)
=SEND.KEYS("foo.py~";TRUE)
=SEND.KEYS("exit~")
=RETURN()
```

It opens a cmd instance, show it for a split second (can't use SEND.KEYS without it being the active app), writes the name of the python script and presses enter, before quitting.

I would like if it didn't need to show the cmd window, but it works for now. Perhaps there'll be another way, but if anyone else wanna do what I did, it does work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to get the book out - Excel 4 came with one book called the Function Reference which listed all the commands available.

Commands that we used back in the day were:

EXEC: starts another program

EXECUTE: runs commands in another program called by Initiate

INITIATE: sets a channel to a program

SEND.KEYS: sends keystrokes to a program (we used to send data to a slow server this way...)

Not sure what will be on the web for Excel macro 4, it was retired as vba came out and Excel moved over...

I still use my copy of the book, but it would be worth finding, although the help should list the commands as well. I just used the book as I had macros running...

Comment: Do you have any idea how to name python as the app_text in Initiate?

Comment: As I am over 60, probably not... but you run Exec then Initiate...